# Rating star not working

Tags: html, css

Hi i have rating star using html and css.I try to use `:checked` in css code
but the rating star can't hold the rating value.So how can i keep the rating value.Any suggestion about this.Thanks for support

Here is html

```
<div class="rate-container">
  <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
</div>
```

Css

```
.rate-container > i {
        float: right;
    }

    .rate-container > i:HOVER,
    .rate-container > i:HOVER ~ i {
        color: gold;
    }
```

Comment: @WinK- i need the html css or js to rate and store in database so it's doesn't matter

Comment: [Here is your answer](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating/demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definetly do this with pure html/css. I made this for my own site a while back. Hopefully this code will suffice to get you going.

The biggest change you'll have to do is to change the `content` property to be `\f005;` with the `font-family: FontAwesome` property, since I used icons instead of font. The rest should be more or less identical.

Good luck!

```
.rating {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    display:none;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
    float: right;
    width: 28px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 200%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #ddd;
    filter: saturate(0);
    -webkit-filter: saturate(0);
    -moz-filter: saturate(0);
    -o-filter: saturate(0);

}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: url("http://i.imgur.com/1dT6Fai.png") ' ';
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    filter: saturate(1);
    -webkit-filter: saturate(1);
    -moz-filter: saturate(1);
    -o-filter: saturate(1);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -o-filter:hue-rotate(-50deg);

}

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-filter: hue-rotate(-50deg);
    -o-filter:hue-rotate(-50deg);

}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fnb7mxt2/)

I should note that this code was inspired by some other source on the net. Unfortunately I don't have a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep selection for the current page like that (but it will not be stored):

```css
.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}
.rating > input {
  display: none;
}
.rating > label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: " \2605";
}
.rating > label {
  float: right;
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: #FFD700;
}
.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label for="star5" title="5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label for="star4" title="4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label for="star3" title="3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label for="star2" title="2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label for="star1" title="1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer based on this: http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest HTML CSS Code for rating.**

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Star Rating.css</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="titleheading">Star Rating Using CSS</div>
<div class="cont" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Rating<span>.css</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="stars">
    <form action="">
      <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
      <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
      <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
      <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <p>click the stars</p>
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="stars">
    <form action="">
      <input class="star star-5" id="star-5-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-5" for="star-5-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-4" id="star-4-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-4" for="star-4-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-3" id="star-3-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-3" for="star-3-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-2" id="star-2-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-2" for="star-2-2"></label>
      <input class="star star-1" id="star-1-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
      <label class="star star-1" for="star-1-2"></label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Your CSS code here- 
**style.css**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,100,300,700,400);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: roboto;
}

body { background: #6bac8b; }
.titleheading{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #FFF;

}
.cont {
  width: 93%;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #970000;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: thin solid #444;
  overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

div.title { font-size: 2em; }

h1 span {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #Fd4;
}

div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

And the output  will be -[image: Output]

[Click To Download Complete Code](https://github.com/sunilrajputboy/star-rating-using-css)